# Trying to validate a modelless form with cakephp3

Tags: php, jquery, validation, cakephp

so I'm kinda new to PHP, and even more so to Cakephp3, and I'm both working with understanding the Cake framework and the interpretation of cake my previous collaborators held, so apologies in advance if what I'm doing is "off".

So I'm trying to acquire and manipulate the information given to me by a post request in a contact form. It may or may not be saved in a table, i'm not sure. But what i'm having trouble with is understanding how the info goes from js to the controller. 
The form html is custom, not created with the validator helper.

So, this is the display action of my contact page controller

```
function display() {

    if($this->request->is('ajax')){  

        $this->viewBuilder()->autoLayout(false); 
        $this->viewBuilder()->layout = 'ajax'; //both these lines do nothing

        echo json_encode($this->request->data); 
        // this information gets displayed inside the $.post function below

        exit;
    }
```

In that same function, i have this code. I'm trying to use it to validate whatever i get with the $.post in js. But it doesn't work. I'm simply trying to require a field with the id of contact_name, which i am assuming that's how it identifies and retrieves the relevant field, but when i submit the form, the log seems to produce me the error array, regardless wether the contact_name is there or not, so from my understanding $errors should be empty if there's no errors but that's not the case

---

```
        $validator = new Validator();
        $validator->requirePresence('contact_name');

        $errors = $validator->errors($data);
        var_dump($errors);
```

And this is the jquery bit

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
'use strict';

enquire.register('screen and (max-width: 480px)', {
    // match: _.bind(this.formBindMobile, this)
});

enquire.register('screen and (min-width: 768px)', {
    // match: _.bind(this.desktopHandler, this)
});

var contactPage = {
    init: function() {
        $(this.variables.formButtonSelector).on('click', _.bind(this.formButtonHandler, this));
        // _.bind(this.validateForm, this);
    },
    variables: {
        formButtonSelector: '.adherence__form__button',
        formSelector: '#adherence__form',
        inputSelector: '.form__input',
        phoneSelector: '#contact_phone',
        nameSelector: '#contact_name',
        emailSelector: '#contact_email',
        timeSelector: '#contact_time',
    },

    formButtonHandler: function() {
        // console.log($(event.currentTarget).parent());
        // $(this.variables.formSelector).submit(this.submitFn());
        this.submitFn();

    },

    submitFn: function() {

        var form = $(this.variables.formSelector),
            actionURL = form.attr('action'),
            formInputs = {
                phoneVal: form.find(this.variables.phoneSelector).val(),
                nameVal: form.find(this.variables.nameSelector).val(),
                emailVal: form.find(this.variables.emailSelector).val(),
                timeVal: form.find(this.variables.timeSelector).val(),
            };

        $.post(actionURL, formInputs, _.bind(this.postForm, this));

    },

    postForm: function(data, status) {

        if(!($.each($(this.variables.inputSelector), this.checkForm))) {
            return;
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }

    },

    checkForm: function(index, element) {
        if($(element).hasClass('js-invalid')) {
            console.log("invalid fields present");
            return false;
        }
        if($(element).val() === "") {
            console.log("empty fields present");
            return false;
        }

    },

};
contactPage.init();
});
```

So in the html, this is an example of an input field in the form

---

```
<input class="form__input form__input--white" 
        type="" 
        name="contact_phone"
        id="contact_phone"
        minlength="9"
        data-pattern-msg  = "Por favor escreva o seu telefone!"
        data-pattern-msg-required = "Escreva o seu telefone"
        data-pattern-msg-minlength = "O seu número de telefone tem que ter no mínimo 9 digitos"
        data-pattern="number"
        data-pattern-keepfocus="true"
        data-pattern-digits="9"
        data-pattern-validateon="blur"
        required
        >
```

So, what I'm asking is it possible to validate what i get from jquery like this, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read this chapter, it is exactly for what you're trying to do https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/form.html#namespace-Cake\Form also read this https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

Comment: Yeah, so I've got in my html a lot of data attributes and a few specific classes, so what i'm saying is, since the modelless form wants to force me to use the form helper, how would I simulate that? Is there a way I can just use my custom form without creating a Form element and have it validated in cake?
Remember I have to change as less as possible of the structure I was given.
I edited the original post with an input field as an example.

Comment: I don't see a problem using the form helper to generate that markup? Read the manual on how to do it https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html